# Why I can't change the font size of last h3 only

Tags: html, css, dom

I'm making a web page containing multiple titles. I have a problem and that is I can't change the font size of h3 (last one) and if I did the whole font sizes of other titles changes too. I want to know why and how to solve this.

This the code

```css
.join_us {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.join_us h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2D2D2D;
}

.join_us .create_account_container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #0EBA00;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.join_us .create_account_container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.invite_for_use_section h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.invite_for_use_section h3 {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2D2D2D;
}
```

```html
<div class="join_us">
  <h3>JOIN OVER 10,000 SMART AFFILIATE MARKETERS! GET STARTED NOW...</h3>
  <div class="create_account_container">
    <a href="">CREATE MY ACCOUNT</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="invite_for_use_section">
  <h1>
    Use Our Secret Tool and Boost Your Commissions Up to 5X More While Cutting Your Workload To Shreds!
  </h1>
  <br>

  <h3>
    Over 10,000 (and growing) People Can't Be Wrong!
  </h3>
</div>
```

The page also contain header which contain h1 titles didn't include it because I think it has no relation to this problem.

Comment: `.invite_for_use_section h3 { font-size: 13px; }` sets the font-size of the last h3 on the page to 13px and is working fine in the code shown here (click Run code snippet).

Comment: But when u change the other font sizes it won't working... It changes all the others... Really wired probelm...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you mean by "it changes all the others", because, given the HTML and CSS given in the question, changing the font size of any selector with an `h3` element in it will not change any of the font-sizes of the other `h3` elements.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the font size of a specific element, try using id's. You can assign an id to an object, like this:

```
<h3 id = "over10">
    Over 10,000 (and growing) People Can't Be Wrong!
  </h3>
```

And to apply styling to that object, in your CSS, you can simply reference that object with a hashtag (#) with its id name, like this:

```
#over10 {
  font-size: 33px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2D2D2D;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I plugged it into code pen and had no problems changing the font size. The only thing I can think of is that H3 is setting a font size which might be overriding the CSS. Trying using a div instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it, thnx guys, i changed the h3 to h5 and h4 ,i think css doesn't allow you to make the font size of an h3 bigger than the font of h1...